# Dagger2 @Provides annotation order issue

Tags: dagger-2, dagger

Say I have MapperModule like below:

```
@Module
public class MapperModule {

    @Singleton @Provides 
    public static ObjectMapper provideObjectMapper () {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }
}
```

Then I import it from the Component like so:

```
@Singleton
@Component (modules={MapperModule.class})

public interface XComponent {

}
```

The MapperModule.class couldn't be found in the Component.

But if I put @Singleton after @Provides, the component interface is able to find the module.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: I don't see a reason that the annotation order would cause the behavior you're seeing. I can only imagine it's a side effect of some other compilation error or saved/unsaved IDE state. Are the files adjacent to each other in a package? If not, does XComponent have a proper import to MapperModule that IntelliJ can resolve?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue after switching the order. It might be a side effect as @JeffBowman suggested